# Can't click New/Import UI Packages

Tags: android-studio, relayjs, figma

I installed Relay plugin for Figma and Android Studio, configured it as in manual. I open Android Studio and can't tap on menu New/Import UI Packages. This button is disabled.

Button is disabled

[image: 1]

I tried to search in web but can't find answer.

Answer (score 1):

the reason is that you didn't add the relay plugin to your grade settings.

Check **Install the Relay Gradle plugin** section https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/relay/install-relay#install-relay